# Can Adobe Analytics record the changes in API?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am working some implementation with Adobe Analytics API.
If any changes in vendor API's may result to break the existing application integration if it is not properly given the upgrades. Is there a mechanism that Adobe Analytics can record the changes in API?

Comment: When you say "changes in API" do you mean when Adobe makes changes to the API endpoint itself (e.g. updating syntax requirements for API payloads, etc.), or changes made to AA that were done from using the API (e.g. updating a segment definition, adding a user, etc.) ?

Comment: not the end point. yes the second one.

Comment: There is a [/auditlogs/usage](https://adobedocs.github.io/analytics-2.0-apis/#/usagelogs) endpoint you can use to get logs of stuff like that. You can also view the logs manually within the Adobe Analytics web interface under Admin > All admin > *(column)* Data configuration & collection > Logs